# Error in fitting mixed model: number of observations <= number of random effects

Tags: r, lme4, model-fitting

I am trying fitting several mixed linear models.

```
 summary(model3 <- lme4::lmer(LPP2POz ~ COND + (COND|ID), data = dataLPP2POz))
```

whose output is

> Error: number of observations (=75) <= number of random effects (=75) for term (COND | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

Can anyone can figure out why this model turns back this error?

Here's the dataset:

```
> dput(head(dataLPP2POz))
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("01", 
"04", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "21", "22", "23", "25", "27", "28", "30", "44", 
"46", "49"), class = "factor"), GR = c("RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP"), SES = c("V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), COND = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC"
), class = "factor"), LPP2POz = c(7.91468942320841, 9.94838815736199, 
10.2186482048953, 1.07455889922813, 1.65917850515029, 3.22422743232682
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Look at this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193678/number-of-random-effects-is-not-correct-in-lmer-model

Comment: I've read it. What does that exaclty mean? That syntax is wrong because of lackness of more observations?

Comment: you are trying to estimate the same number of random effects on ID as there are observations per ID. I believe you can still perform the analysis but have to specify in the argument. Check here: `?lmerControl`

Comment: I did, but honestrly I'm not able to figure out what to do

Comment: I believe its `check.nobs.vs.nRE` which is by default set to `stop`. You can set this to `ignore` inside `lmerControl()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification `COND + (COND|ID)` indicates that there is a fixed effect of condition and a random effect of condition across individuals; that is, every individual/condition combination gets a random-effect value. Approximately

```
y_ij = alpha_i + epsilon_{c,ij} + epsilon_{r,ij}
```

(although that's not quite how `lmer` parameterizes it); `alpha_i` is the fixed effect of condition `i`, `epsilon_{c,ij}` is the random effect for condition `i` for individual `j`, and `epsilon_{r,ij}` is the *residual variation* for condition `i`/individual `j`.  The problem is that **because every individual is only measured once in every condition, the two `epsilon` terms are confounded (jointly unidentifiable)**.

- As @Bloxx says, you can force `lmer` to fit the model anyway by specifying `control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")` in your `lmer()` call. If you do this, though, you can't interpret the random effects covariance matrix unless you are an expert/really know what you're doing (the fixed effects should still be OK).
- If you wanted to fit the same model in `glmmTMB` you could set `dispformula = ~0` to zero out the residual variance (actually it gets set to a very small but non-zero value ...)
- For some kinds of simpler models (but not this one), as in [this example](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/uqam/mixedlab1.html), you could simplify the random effects model so that it no longer clashed with the residual variance term. For example, if your model was `(1|ID/COND)` instead (i.e. a compound symmetric model/intercept variation of `ID` and `COND` within `ID`, equivalent to `(1|ID) + (1|ID:COND)`) you could solve the problem by dropping the nested term (which is exactly the same as the residual variance term) and simplify the model to `(1|ID)`.