# How to fit quickly mixed models by using an iterative method on a long format dataset

Tags: r, data-structures, lme4

I need to fit a mixed model with both ID and GROUP (COND) variables for the following dataset:

```
   ID    GR    SES   COND    signals   value
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <fct>     <dbl>
 1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3FCz   -11.6  
 2 01    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3FCz   -11.1  
 3 01    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3FCz    -4.00 
 4 04    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3FCz    -0.314
 5 04    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3FCz     0.239
 6 04    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3FCz     5.04 
 7 06    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3FCz    -0.214
 8 06    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3FCz    -2.96 
 9 06    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3FCz    -1.97 
10 07    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3FCz    -2.83 
# ... with 965 more rows
```

where signals variable is not a predictor variable, but it is just a nominal variable. Since there are 12 king of signals and to each of this corresponds a spefic range of value into the beside column (value), I would like to know whether by using this data long setting it is possible to run the lmer() function by using COND and ID as fixed and random effects, via an iterative function (such as for loop, map(), apply() functions and so on).    If don't, how this will be supposed to be written for iterating analysis on data set as a wide format?

If possible I would like to extract iteratively diagnostic plot (if included) by each fitted model. Thanks for those ones who will answer.

Here the dataset

```
> dput(head(out_long, 50))
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "04", "04", "04", "06", 
"06", "06", "07", "07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "09", "09", "09", 
"10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "13", "13", 
"13", "15", "15", "15", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "18", 
"18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "21", "21", "21", "22", "22"), 
    GR = c("RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
    "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
    "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
    "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
    "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
    "RP"), SES = c("V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
    "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC"
    ), signals = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("P3FCz", 
    "P3Cz", "P3Pz", "LPPearlyFCz", "LPPearlyCz", "LPPearlyPz", 
    "LPP1FCz", "LPP1Cz", "LPP1Pz", "LPP2FCz", "LPP2Cz", "LPP2Pz", 
    "LPP2POz"), class = "factor"), value = c(-11.6312151716924, 
    -11.1438413285935, -3.99591470944713, -0.314155675382471, 
    0.238885648959708, 5.03749946898385, -0.213621915029167, 
    -2.96032491743069, -1.97168681693488, -2.83109425298642, 
    1.09291198163802, -6.692991645215, 4.23849942428043, 2.9898889629932, 
    3.5510699900835, 9.57481668808606, 5.4167795618285, 1.7067607715475, 
    -6.13036076093477, -2.82955734597919, -2.50672211111696, 
    0.528517585832501, 8.16418133488309, 1.88777321897925, -7.73588468896919, 
    -9.83058052401056, -6.97442700196932, 1.27327945355082, 2.11962397764132, 
    0.524299677616254, -1.83310726842883, 0.658810483381172, 
    -0.261373488428192, 4.37524298634374, 0.625555654900511, 
    3.19617639836154, 0.0405517582137798, -3.29357103412113, 
    -0.381435057304614, -5.73445509910268, -6.1129152355645, 
    -2.45744234877604, 2.95352732001065, 0.527721249096473, 1.91803490989119, 
    -3.46703346467546, -2.40438419043702, -5.35374408162217, 
    -7.27028665849262, -7.1532211375959)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

PLease just let me know whether you will need the wide format dataset.

Comment: Maybe `sp<-split(out_long, out_long$signals)` and `map` or `lapply` the model to each `sp` member? Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: Could you show me an example here as follows?

Comment: `lapply(sp, function(DF) <model(formula, data = DF>)`. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've tried entering in the pipe chain I've used to create the long dataset the function  `group_split(signals)` and then to run the `lapply(out_long_list, function(.x) 
  {lmer(value ~ ID + COND + COND:ID + (COND|ID), data = out_long_list)})`. It does not work. Maybe it would be better have a clear example if you do not mind, as I am not that expert in using these iterative methods

Comment: If I'm not wrong the one thing I'm looking for is to create a kind list of models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could probably run the models for each signal. With the posted data it gives an error (see [this post of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743835/error-in-fitting-mixed-model-number-of-observations-number-of-random-effects)) stating that there are too few observations.

Note that the formula

```
ID + COND + COND:ID
```

is equivalent to the shorter

```
ID*COND
```

Now the fitting code.

```
library(lme4)

out_long_list <- split(out_long, out_long$signals)

i <- sapply(out_long_list, nrow) != 0
models_list <- lapply(out_long_list[i], function(DF){
  tryCatch(lmer(value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = DF),
           error = function(e) e)
})

lapply(model_list, summary)
```

---

A `tidyverse` solution could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

out_long %>%
  group_by(signals) %>%
  do(fit = lmer(value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = .))
```

Comment: If I try corrcetiung it as `models_list <- lapply(out_long_list, function(DF){
  lmer(value ~ ID*COND + (1|COND), data = DF)`
}) it turns back this error `Error in is.nloptr(ret) : objective in x0 returns NA`

Comment: Are you using `tidy` or `broom.mixed`

Comment: This base model doesn't make sense. All ID/COND combinations are included both in the fixed effect (`ID*COND`) and in the random effects  `(COND|ID)`. Even if you simplify the random effects to `(1|ID)`, you still have a fixed-effect *and* a random-effect parameter for each level of `ID`. I think you may need to give a little bit of thought to your basic question before tackling the more complex do-it-for-all-signals problem ...

Comment: @akrun I've tried using both the solution. Indeed by simplifying the model I've obtained some outcomes (I've run `lmer((value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = DF))`). However they lack of the estimate,  St.Error, t value and Pr<t...

Comment: @mały_statystyczny `lapply` `summary` to the `model_list` to get t statistics.

Comment: I don't really know my way around grouping/ungrouping/do/etc. in tidyverse.  `broom.mixed::tidy(., effects="fixed"))` is probably the quickest way to get summaries in the tidyverse example (but as I said, I don't know how to embed that in the pipeline)

Comment: @BenBolker I prefer base R for that. It's simpler, the same method can be applied to many other problems and there are many resources where to learn from: [JSS](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01), or [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/12/a-quick-primer-on-split-apply-combine-problems/) and many others.

Comment: I don't mind either way. I was just pointing out that your tidyverse example could be extended.  There might be some advantage to replacing your `lapply()` example with `purrr::map_dfr(model_list, broom.mixed::tidy, .id = "model")`

Comment: @Ben Bolker Hi, I've tried calling the aforementioned `purrr::map_dfr(model_list, broom.mixed::tidy, .id = "model")` command. It seems to work but I have the problem to split and rename the model for each signals names. That will make clearer the output to be interpreted, even though I have some trouble. Otherwise @Rui Barradas by running the `lapply(models_list, function(x){summary(models_list)})` I am not able to see the statistics at all...Is there anything wrong??

Comment: @RuiBarradas ok I got them....I've just fixed turned the `summary(models_list)` into `summary(x)`

Comment: @mały_statystyczny Simpler and already in my answer is `lapply(model_list, summary)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks, pal. Very instructive. If you reckon this question useful, then I kindly invite you to vote it up, if you want. No constrain, of course ;)

Comment: @BenBolker I'd like to improve the table I get from the code you've suggested too. Actually I'm facing with a table with as many rows as the created variable `model`. Could you please suggest any solution in case I would like to get rid of  `model`. columns and assign to each chuck the  `signals` name? Thank you so much